# How can I stop Rails from URL encoding already URL encoded parameters when using UrlHelpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, urlencode

I have a route set up like this:

```
get '/:permalink', to: 'article_view#view', as: :view, permalink: /.*/
```

When I call it like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.view_url(p)
```

The permalink gets url encoded. The permalinks are saved URL encoded in our database, as  for instance "h%C3%B8st", as opposed to "høst". However, the url ends up like this: "http://example.com/h%25C3%25B8st" (note the double encoding). How can I stop this from happening without building my own URLs?

Comment: You could store unencoded versions in your db.

Comment: That database already has millions of rows, so no.

Comment: If there's will, there's a way. You can unencode existing data.

Answer (score 0):

if `p` is already encoded then use CGI.unescape(p) to reverse the encoding.

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.view_url(CGI.unescape(p))

p = "h%C3%B8st"
CGI.unescape(p)
#=> "høst"
```

Comment: I thought about that, but that seems to be going about it the wrong way, tbh. It should be possible to tell Rails "this url parameter is already encoded, don't do it for me"?

Comment: Does it affect performance? I get that it's not perfect, but it does the job and it works. If it doesn't impact performance then do it until something better comes along.

Comment: And if it does impact performance then rewrite the other code to store them unencoded and unencode the ones currently in the DB. If "millions of rows" is stopping you then you might reexamine your role. The "easiest" way is to implement the solution I gave you, then add a new column to the table that has all of the same properties as this one, and set a  job to copy an unencoded version to the new column. It can run when demand is low. Then you swap the two columns' names.

Comment: And if you can't stand to do any of that, dig into the rails code that is causing it to be double encoded, and write a method that overrides that when needed.

Comment: And if none of this works for you, rethink how and why you are using a path to retrieve a string stored in the db. You could have something like ` <a href="<%= @something.permalink %>" > Permalink or whatever text </a>`